# What happens to businesses, properties, entire towns and counties after the US Supreme Court ruling on Tribal Lands?

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court

[A recent ruling by the Supreme Cour](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-53358330)t basically just said that half of the State is Tribal Lands. Tribal Lands are not taxable from what I researched.**There are entire towns, counties, homes, businesses all owned by non-Native American people on tribal lands.**

### Two Questions

They (*non-native Americans*) no longer own the land, so what happens to the tax laws in regards to property they never owned?

What legal avenues could the Native Americans do if they wanted all non-native Americans to leave?

Comment: This is gonna be fun, I can't wait when businesses have to pay rent bills. They are gonna be loaded with money!! Smarter to keep them there and instead of kicking them out.

Comment: Your landlord?? Opps... He no longer owns the land!! No rent to him!

Comment: I think you misunderstand the ruling.

Comment: Let's all take the oath: We will never again take a news headline at face value.

Answer (score 2):

The [opinion in McGirt](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/591/18-9526/) did not say that "you no longer own the land": nothing regarding property has changed. The ruling holds that Congress did not disestablish the Creek reservation, contrary to the position argued by Oklahoma. The primary consequences relate to enforcement of state law, and state taxation (really, a consequence of state law enforcement). In that respect, property questions on the Creek reservation are not different from the same question on any other reservation (likewise, law enforcement questions). Congress has always permitted the sale of reservation land by a tribe to non-members. Apart from the jurisdiction question for the underlying crime in question (and future enforcement of e.g. hunting and fishing regulations), the effect will be on jurisdiction questions, and the tax question (states cannot tax Indians on Indian land).